# Dealing with a tsan lock-order-inversion false positive

Tags: c++, multithreading, clang, thread-sanitizer

I have code which is identified by tsan as lock-order-inversion. It is a false positive. I know I can use suppression files to prevent this but I wonder whether I can do something with my code so that my intention is clearer and it doesn't get misidentified. Here's what I'm doing:

```cpp
void addObject(ObjectData objectData) {
    unique_lock listLock(listMutex);
    ObjectPtr obj = list.createObject(objectData);
    // we need to lock the object here because it's created but not finalized
    // finalization can take time and we don't want to keep the list locked 
    // during that time so that other objects can be added or gotten
    obj->mutex.lock();
    listLock.unlock();

    obj->finalize();
    obj->mutex.unlock();    
}

void cloneObject(ObjectName name) {
    shared_lock listLock(listMutex);
    auto obj = list.getObjectByName(name);
    listLock.unlock();

    // will wait here if object is not finalized
    unique_lock objLock(obj->mutex);
    addObject(obj->data());
}
```

Here's what tsan observed:

```
threadA => addObject => list.lock success
threadA => addObject => objX.lock success LIST IS LOCKED
threadA => addObject => list.unlock
// and later:
threadB => cloneObject => objX.lock success
threadB => cloneObject => addObject => list.lock success OBJX IS LOCKED
```

Here's what it's warning me could happen:

```
threadA => addObject => list.lock success
threadB => cloneObject => objX.lock success
threadA => addObject => objX.lock waiting
threadB => cloneObject => addObject => list.lock DEAD LOCK
```

The thing is this **can't happen** as the only time addObject acquires an object lock is IF the object was just created and there is no way to have a successful lock on an object which could lead to the same object being locked in `addObject`. Calling `addObject` from `cloneObject` will produce an object lock, but this will necessarily be another object and not the one being cloned.

Comment: You should not create the object on the list. Then you don't need to lock the object, and you only need to lock the list while adding the already finished object.

Comment: With what I have, many threads can get the object, start working on other things and only block when they need the finalized object (which is not always what they need... they might only need the metadata, which is already available)

Comment: What I hear you saying is that no threads can get the object. They can get a second thing called the object metadata.

Comment: ... which magically turns into an object when you need it to.

But yeah.